Is this how a single phase transformer is connected to multiple houses?
Single phase transformer serving 3 houses:

I am not sure if this correct. Can someone confirm?

Your depiction of the American Split-phase Electrical Power Distribution System is okay except for the neutral grounding not being shown correctly.
Utility power in North America is distributed via single-phase transformers with their primaries being fed 12.47 kV using 2 lines of a three-phase system or 7.2 kV using a line and neutral.
Here's the appropriate schematic.

The distribution transformers, which are pole-mounted, are also known as a 'pole pigs'.
The neutral is grounded at the pole.
The service drop for each consumer has 3 cables for L1, L2 & N.

Thank you, Graham!

Yes, that is correct.
In my area, there is also a connection from Neutral to a ground rod at each transformer.

ah.. thanks. I forgot about the ground. Thanks for the clarification!
